# add X amount of blank array at the end of multidimentional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am working with array and database, so when i select records from database it will return me with random number of result, Means sometime it returns 3 records, sometime 0 and sometime more than 8. So what i want is, to add X amount of blank array at the end of array.

For example.

If i get 3 records from select query of MySQL database, Add 5 more empty records at the end of array, so it become 8 length of array.

```
$temp=array();
while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    $temp[]=$rs[0];
}
```

I am adding selected records in new array like this, but needs to add X amount of blank array to make array length in total 8.

Comment: you want to add new index to array which is returned from mysql query??

Comment: `for($i = count($temp); $i < 8; $i++) $temp[]= [];`

Answer (score 0):

Create another loop that will add empty array:

```
$temp=array();
while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    $temp[]=$rs[0];
}

//2nd loop
$arraySize = 8 - sizeOf($temp);
for($i = 0; $i < $arraySize ; $i++) 
       $temp[]= [];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this without the while loop

```
$array = array();
for($x=0; $x<=7; $x++)
{
   $array[] = isset($rs[$x]) ? $rs[$x] : "";
}
```